# NTC layout for MOSFET temperature sensing

Tags: pcb-design, sensor, temperature, layout, thermistor

Here is a picture where there is a NTC (RT501) that is surrounded by a solder ring connected to the copper pour of the drain of the MOSFETs. Any reason why the layout the way it is with the ring? Also what would be the optimal way to place a SMD NTC for MOSFET temperature sensing in terms of accuracy?

The MOSFETs are high current (50-100A) ON/OFF switches, not in a DC-DC design.
[image]

Comment: "Any reason why" -- yes, probably. But we can only guess at the original design intent. "Optimal" -- optimal for what? What application (switching, linear, pulsed, etc.), what parameters (accuracy, time constant, isolation, noise, cost, etc.) to optimize over?

Comment: Another question is what the green goo in the upper right corner and the white goo on the cooling pads is supposed to be. Thermal paste? Peelable masking? Something else?

Comment: Thanks Tim for the question. I've clarified in the question I've asked.

Comment: The grey goo is likely thermal paste as they have similar material to connect to heat sink on the bottom side of the PCB. Green one maybe some paint spill over while marking the screw position to hold the PCB, not sure. .

Comment: Why the use of thermal paste if everything's soldered down anyway?

Comment: Maybe the thermal paste leaked through the unmasked vias from the bottom? Not sure, since the top is tented.

Comment: @EarthLord I'm pretty sure that if one asks the soldering gurus they'll tell you that themal paste is a no-no for parts with a cooling pad. It's not entirely clear what the footprint of these parts is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That SMD thermistor is quite possibly for OTP (over-temperature protection) that, for example, stops the system when the measured temperature exceeds some level (e.g. 125°C).

> Any reason why the layout the way it is with the ring?

The ring has an electrical (and therefore, thermal) connection with the drain/collector pour. The idea behind making it that way could be (a hard guess) make sure that area the thermistor sits on gets heated by the drain/collector pour (only, or more than other components/places) so that the thermistor resistance changes mostly by the drain/collector temperature.

---

I did a similar thing in one of my recent power supply designs:

[image]

The XTH401 sits between the synchronous rectifier MOSFETs. It's there for OTP that brings a latched stop once the temperature goes beyond 120°C. This placement brings a good behaviour because,

- the thermistor is in pretty much close proximity to the MOSFETs,
- and the thermistor is "shadowed" by the MOSFETs' bodies.

So the resistance changes almost only by the MOSFETs' thermal radiation (from the body) and conduction (from drain to the pour to the PCB). Even with that the thermistor temperature is about 10-12°C lower than the actual MOSFET temperature measured from the drain solder point but this is acceptable for the main purpose.

For your circuit placing the thermistor between the MOSFETs may not be electrically possible because it'd create a hole (isolated area) on the drain/collector pour which can affect the overall performance.

---

> Also what would be the optimal way to place a SMD NTC for MOSFET temperature sensing in terms of accuracy?

There's no "optimal" way. All of the methods depend on the requirements (accuracy, purpose, cost, etc) and conditions (operating parameters, size, cooling, placement, etc).

If you want to measure/monitor the MOSFET temperatures accurately then you must think about contact-based and non-SMD ways.